# Is $g(x) = gxg$ a group action?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-actions

Let $G=X$. Is the following a group action?

$$g(x)=gxg$$

If it is, what's the stablizer?

I had troubles with the second group action axiom. I wasn't sure if I did correctly. Also, on a side note, if the group action is on itself, isn't the first axiom always correct by the associativity of a group?

Comment: Write out $(gh)(x)$ and $g(h(x))$. Notice anything?

Comment: However, $g(x) = g x g^{-1}$ will be a (left) action.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by Alex G. in the comments, it is not a group action as $(gh)\cdot x = ghxgh$ whereas $g\cdot(h\cdot x) = g\cdot (hxh) = ghxhg$.

As for your second question, the answer is no. Consider the map $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$ given by $a\cdot n = an$. This does not satisfy the first group action axiom despite the fact that the group is 'acting' on itself.